# Install4j:Difference between Event type cancelled and after rollback action

Tags: java, install4j

I want to replace changed files with original files on installer rollback/failure. On which install4j event type, I should perform this replacement of files-'cancelled' or 'after rollback action' ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! This isn't a code-generating service, so you'll have to show some effort and research the issue some on your own - show us what you tried and what you *think* might be a solution, and we'll gladly work from that!

Answer (score 1):

For cancelled installer action you can use `EventType.CANCELLED`. Here's a sample:

```
context.addInstallerEventListener(new InstallerEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == EventType.CANCELLED) {
            // custom rollback
        }
    }
});
```

and it will work perfectly. It is called after all actions are rolled back.

Didn't use 'after rollback action', but I can strongly recommend this method.